# Windows 10 User ID Doesn't Appear In User List

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

One of the applications that I use (DB2) creates custom user groups, and one of the setup steps is to add my Windows 10 user account to these groups to grant access. I'm on Windows 10 Enterprise, and the issue I'm having is that my user ID doesn't appear in the list of users. Below is a screenshot of what I see when I run `lusrmgr.msc`.

[image]

When I check my account within the control panel, my user ID shows as my company email address. I was expecting to see something like `AzureAD\MyName`.

Can anyone help me understand why my own user ID wouldn't appear in the list of users? How do I correct this?

Comment: Try to check the following:
1. User Name Length
2. Naming restrictions for windows
3. The right of Installation user account
4. Are the user account created during an installation or the original local user accounts?
Reference:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0508wasserman/index.html